# Netbeans does not recognize library added with maven (gson)

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, gson

I have a maven project in netbeans. I want to add google's gson library to my project. I right clicked the Dependencies item under my project and selected Add Dependency. Then I typed com.google.code.gson and selected 2.4 [jar]. The dependency appears to be added correctly, however when I try to use classes from the library, nothing is available, only "class". (See screenshot)

[image]

This is what my project looks like

[image]

I can import the packages, but cannot use them. Please help me.

Comment: You might need to do a clean/build

Comment: Thank you, that worked. Please post it as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: @MadProgrammer see my comment above.

Comment: Post and self answer =)